# .htaccess forward local to remote on 404

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, forward

I do all of my development locally on sites that use a CMS. We have a directory that is used to store user-uploaded content, such as images (/assets/). The problem is, when developing locally, I don't want all of the uploaded files from the production site on my machine, so I leave this directory empty, and all of the HTTP requests for files in the /assets/ directory get 404'ed.

What would be great is if I could have a rewrite rule in my .htaccess that detects the 404, and forwards to the external URL of the production site to load the asset from there. The logic would be:

```
Request localhost/somesite/assets/foo.jpg
200 response ? send the local file /somesite/assets/foo.jpg
404 ? forward to http://www.productionsite.com/assets/foo.jpg
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry, the formatting didn't come through. The logic, if it's not clear, should be that if the HTTP response is 200, send the local file to the browser. If it's a 404, go to http://www.productionsite.com/assets/the_requested_file.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your .htaccess rules like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(assets/.*)$ http://www.productionsite.com/$1 [R,L,NC]
```

This will make sure that any request matching `/assets/` and **doesn't already exist** on your local webserver will be **externally redirected** to `http://www.productionsite.com/assets/...`

Answer (score 0):

Is /assets always on another site, or only if the files are not available locally?

The reason I ask is that it may be simpler to always redirect just /assets to the live with the following (untested) rules in httpd.conf/.htaccess on your development server:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 ^(assets) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.livesite.com/$1 [L]
```

Comment: That looks really good, but what is "enter code here?" Ideally, we only look to the remote if the file 404s locally, because there is a chance that someone could upload stuff locally that is not yet on the remote server.

Comment: Edited! That was me being a newbie!

Comment: Another idea, is it possible to use a squid proxy for just those requests? I have no off-the-shelf answer, however, I like your workflow idea and would like to implement something similar. Surely some proxy program could do it?